# Select 3 tables with multiple "on clause" affecting 9 lines with only one register?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have these 3 tables: Register, Brand and Clothing, where Register saves int numbers from a Brand dropdownlist and a Clothing dropdownlist, but in the select I dont want the int value, but the value who the respective tables represents. (IdBrand 1 = Nike, IdBrand 2 = Adidas). It is "working" but I dont know if I am doing something wrong, cause when I try the code on Sql Server "new query" I have 9 lines resulting even I having JUST ONE REGISTER on the RegisterTable, it is more a "logic" question, is it normal to have a lots of rows on the "select display"?

The Code

```
select Register.*, Clothing.ClothingName, Brand.BrandName
from Register

inner join Clothing 
on RegisterClothingId1 = ClothingId
or RegisterClothingId2 = ClothingId
or RegisterClothingId3 = ClothingId

inner join Brand
on RegisterBrandId1 = BrandId
or RegisterBrandId2 = BrandId
or RegisterBrandId3 = BrandId
```

I also try with "and" instead "or" but it affects/returns zero lines.
Again, this code "is working". I just do not know if it is normal to have so many lines resulting with JUST ONE register. Because if 1 register gives 9 lines I wonder 100 register will give 900 lines for example.
Thank you.

The table have only 3 Brand columns and 3 Clothing columns that inherats from the other 2 tables

Register Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Register] (
    [RegisterId]            INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RegisterPersonId]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [RegisterPersonNote]    NCHAR (60)      NULL,
    [RegisterCareerId]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [RegisterEvent]         NCHAR (60)      NOT NULL,
    [RegisterEventYear]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [RegisterImgDressed]    VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [RegisterClothingId1]   INT             NOT NULL,
    [RegisterBrandId1]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [RegisterClothingName1] NCHAR (60)      NOT NULL,
    [RegisterClothingImg1]  VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [RegisterClothingId2]   INT             NOT NULL,
    [RegisterBrandId2]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [RegisterClothingName2] NCHAR (60)      NOT NULL,
    [RegisterClothingImg2]  VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [RegisterClothingId3]   INT             NOT NULL,
    [RegisterBrandId3]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [RegisterClothingName3] NCHAR (60)      NOT NULL,
    [RegisterClothingImg3]  VARBINARY (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [RegisterYoutube]       NCHAR (500)     NOT NULL,
    [RegisterExternalLink]  NCHAR (500)     NULL,
    [RegisterNote]          NCHAR (60)      NULL,
    [RegisterNote2]         NCHAR (60)      NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Register] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RegisterId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Register_Brand1] FOREIGN KEY ([RegisterBrandId1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Brand] ([BrandId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Register_Brand2] FOREIGN KEY ([RegisterBrandId2]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Brand] ([BrandId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Register_Brand3] FOREIGN KEY ([RegisterBrandId3]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Brand] ([BrandId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Register_Clothing1] FOREIGN KEY ([RegisterClothingId1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clothing] ([ClothingId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Register_Clothing2] FOREIGN KEY ([RegisterClothingId2]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clothing] ([ClothingId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Register_Clothing3] FOREIGN KEY ([RegisterClothingId3]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clothing] ([ClothingId])
);
```

Other two are simple tables, have only BrandId and BrandName, and Clothing Id and ClothingName

Comment: Problem in Join, Can you show the table structure ?

Comment: @SankarRaj already update the question, thank you :)

Comment: By the way, since I have Brand 1,2 and 3; and Clothing 1,2 and 3. So I wonder I should have 6 result lines on Select (3x2) I dont know why 9, cant even imagine why

Comment: Your first join will produce 3 rows and all this 3 rows have 3 brand ids (3 rows x 3 Brands/Cols - so the second join will produce 9 recors). And this may change as per the values stored in the RegisterClothingId1, RegisterBrandId3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Register table needs redesign. Columns with name[RegisterClothingNameX] and [RegisterClothingImgX] should be on the Clothing table unless they are not describing a particular clothing item. Below query should give you the data you require

```
select 
Register.*, 
c1.ClothingName AS Clothing1Name, 
c2.ClothingName AS Clothing2Name, 
c3.ClothingName AS Clothing3Name, 
b1.BrandName AS Brand1Name,
b2.BrandName AS Brand2Name,
b3.BrandName AS Brand3Name
from 
Register

INNER JOIN Clothing c1 ON RegisterClothingId1 = c1.ClothingId
INNER JOIN Clothing c2 ON RegisterClothingId2 = c2.ClothingId
INNER JOIN Clothing c3 ON RegisterClothingId3 = c3.ClothingId

INNER JOIN Brand b1 ON RegisterBrandId1 = b1.BrandId
INNER JOIN Brand b2 ON RegisterBrandId2 = b2.BrandId
INNER JOIN Brand b3 ON RegisterBrandId3 = b3.BrandId
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first join will produce 3 rows and all this 3 rows have 3 brand ids (3 rows x 3 Brands/Cols - so the second join will produce 9 records). And this may change as per the values stored in the RegisterClothingId1, RegisterBrandId3